# Java: User defined String, that points to an Array

Tags: java, arrays, string, object

Basically I have a method that takes a `String` *name* and will delete that entry if found.
I have a `LinkedList` composed of 26 `LinkedList` instances, named (alphabetically) as follows a, b, c, ..., z

Lets say when the user enters a word like "*Charlie*" so I want to delete it.

*Charlie* starts with '**c**' so how can I make my code point to the `LinkedList` **c** without having to traverse all the `LinkedList` items.

So far I get the name *Charlie*, get `char` at 0 index, convert it to lowercase and call it `String` Letter. Is there a way to do [Letter].remove(name);

I asked a similar question but I don't think I wrote it well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should take a look closer into the java API and try not to reinvent the wheel. Basically you can use a `HashMap` to wrap you `LinkedList` instances instead of using a `LinkedList` because it will let you select your items based on a key (the alphabet characters in your case)

```
Map<Character,LinkedList> myMap = new HashMap<Character,LinkedList>();
```

After having filled your `Map` (simply calling `myMap.put('c', new LinkedList())` and so on for each char), you can get the desired `LinkedList`, without having to iterate through the whole map:

```
myMap.get('c');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a trie data structure.

If you still want to do it using your approach, Instead of having a linked list of lists, try having an array of arrays.Might come in handy